# Project Tango C API mapping specific 3D point to color

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

I am using Project Tango C API. I signed up to color image and depth image callbacks(TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable and TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable). So I do have TangoPointCloud and matching TangoImageBuffer. I've rendered them separately and they are valid. So I understand that I essentially can loop through each 3D point now in TangoPointCloud and do whatever I want with them. The trouble is I also want the corresponding color for each 3D point.

The Tango standard examples have lots of examples such as drawing depth and color separately or do OpenGL texture on depth image but they don't have a simple sample that maps 3D point to its color.

I tried TangoSupport_projectCameraPointToDistortedPixel but it gives weird results. I also tried TangoXYZij approach but it is obsolete.

Please those who achieved this help, I wasted two days going back and forth with this.